# Active Admin: ArgumentError in Sessions#new (Rails 4.1.0.beta1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Active Admin is giving me the following error on a clean install using edge Rails (4.1.0.beta1)

```
ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new
wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

Extracted source (around line #5):
<%= active_admin_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => send(:"#{scope}_session_path"), :html => { :id => "session_new" }) do |f|
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous', branch: 'rails-4.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this as well.

This is happening because Rails 4.1 removes the fifth parameter `block` from the `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` constructor.

There's a patch in formtastic master that fixes this. You can use `gem "formtastic", github: "justinfrench/formtastic"`in your Gemfile.

Comment: Quick addition: When you actually try to use active admin to inspect your models, you'll run into an issue with the ransack gem. To fix this, use the rails 4.1 branch:

`gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack", branch: "rails-4.1"`

Answer (score 3):

Got mine working by removing **gem "meta_search"** from my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can try is update devise to latest master, seems good people at devise did some work on rails 4.1 compatibility - there was a `Merge pull request #2822 from plataformatec/rails-4.1` pull request merge 19 hours ago, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commits/master

If that fails then answer is "don't use edge rails", according to AAs commit history there was no work done on making AA work with edge rails and one would think that at least slight tweaks would be necessary for this, it's highly possible the good folk at AA simply didn't get around to do it considering `4.1 beta1` release was just before holidays https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commits/master